# goes back to home page when refreshing jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a website with functionality of jquery for navigation. I use the load() function of jquery that enables the website to be navigated without refresh. But when I hit f5 for refresh for example I am in the Contact Us page it will hit back on the index page which is the parent page. Is there a way in jquery or ajax to focus on the page loaded when hitting refresh rather than redirecting it to the index.php page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use some form of history navigation. [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) is a great plugin that allows you to use both real URLs and ajax loading functionality.

You could also implement it by simply changing `window.location.hash` when you load new content. Then when the page is loaded, you could check `window.location.hash` and load the relevant content.